# sifr text not appearing at all in IE9

Tags: sifr, internet-explorer-9, sifr3

I have a test site using sIFR perfectly (domain is http://80.175.49.36/) but the text is not displaying in IE9 win 7. It works in compatability mode, IE8 / 7 / Firefox / Safari on Mac. I have seen people having problems with streched text, but I am just not seeing anything at all - any ideas on this guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using the latest sIFR version r437 which can be downloaded from [here](http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/nightlies/).